# kog maw dmg reduce on on-hits

Tags: league-of-legends

In the new patch kog maws W increases the attack speed but reduces the damage to non minions by 55%.

Does this damage reduce include on-hit effects? Does it decrease the bonus damage on the spell (1,25% per 100 ad 0,75% per 100 ap)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say no, only the base damage of the auto attack is reduced. Quoting from the wiki (bold emphasis is mine):

> Bio-Arcane Barrage
>
> ACTIVE: For 6 seconds, Kog'Maw gains bonus attack range, doubles his total attack speed and attack speed cap, also halving his ability cast times, and causes each of his basic attacks to deal 「 1.25% per 100 AD 」 (+ 「 0.75% per 100 AP) 」 of target's maximum health bonus magic damage, capped at 100 against minions and monsters.
>
> While Bio-Arcane Barrage is active, Kog'Maw's basic attacks deal 55% damage to non-minions, though **on-hit effects are still fully applied**.

It appears the bonus damage and on-hit effects are still fully applied (since the bonus damage likely counts as an on-hit effect), without any damage reduction. So only the base auto attack damage will be reduced to 55%.

Comment: i must have missed that on my read through the wiki, thanks

Comment: No problem at all, easy to miss things like that :)